Combine :target: and :download: in sphinx-doc
If I have this tree file in sphinx-doc project directory
_build
index.rst
...
foo.rst
foo/myimage.jpeg
foo/myvideo.webm

I want to display in foo.rst image foo/myimage.jpeg which links to foo/myvideo.webm.
I tried:
|My target image|


.. |My target image| image:: foo/myimage.jpeg
   :target: :download:`foo/myvideo.webm`

but it does not work: the image links to
:download:`foo/myvideo.webm`

It would be equivalent to markdown:
[![My target image](foo/myimage.jpeg)](foo/myvideo.webm)

Update (2024-11-13): I cannot put myimage.jpeg and myvideo.webm into _static directory. I need to sphinx copy them to _build directory. Because of that I use :download: directive. Really I want:

sphinx copy foo/myimage.jpeg and foo/myvideo.webm into _build
show image.jpeg and when I press the image, it goes to myvideo.webm


I don't get it. What are you trying to achieve? Is it an image that links to a video file? Like this? Why the :download:?

@sinoroc Just link image to a file which is not in _static dir.

If the point of :download: is to have Sphinx copy the file in the right place, then why not have two links to the webm file? Make one text link (hidden somewhere in a page?) with :download: and one image link with :target:.

@sinoroc So the answer is "it can't"
